# how to make bootstrap 3 responsive navbar with full sized search form in the middle?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a navbar containing a search form that will fill all the remaining space between the `.navbar-brand` and the content of `.navbar-collapse`.

when the viewport's width is less than 767px (when the navbar's collapse style is triggered), my code works fine. but when the viewport's width is more than 767px, the search form became small..

here's the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="sr-only"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <div class="navbar-search_container">
        <div class="full_width_div">
          <div class="right_part-wrapper">
            <a class="btn btn-default">z</a>
          </div>
          <div class="remaining-wrapper">
            <form class="my-search_form-group">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" placeholder="keyword">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                    a
                  </button>
                </span>
              </div>
            </form> <!-- /.my-search_form-group -->
          </div> <!-- /.left_part-wrapper -->
        </div> <!-- /.full_width_div -->
      </div> <!-- /.navbar-search_container -->
    </div> <!-- /.navbar-header -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and here's the css:

```
/* css to allow a div fit remaining width
   based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/5043876/1235167 */
.full_width_div {
  width: 100% !important;
}
.full_width_div > .right_part-wrapper {
  /* white-space: nowrap; */
  float: right;
}
.full_width_div > .left_part-wrapper {
  float: left;
}
.full_width_div > .remaining-wrapper {
  /* white-space: nowrap; */
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3qwfv829/1/)

after tinkering with the developer tools, I discovered that my code only works on viewports smaller than 767px because the `.navbar-header` gets a "width:100%" rule when it's below 767px. so now I figured I need to make the `.navbar-search_container` part to fill the remaining space left by the content of `.navbar-collapse`. how do I do that? they're on different DOM level and structure.. please help. I've been working on this for days..

Answer (score 0):

Setting min-width combined with media query might be an option:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .full_width_div {
    min-width: 500px;
  }
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kuu4uuzx/)

Comment: unfortunately, the items in the `.navbar-collapse` can vary, so I can't use a fixed width..

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is interested, since no one seems to have any usable solution basically I gave up on this problem and used two sets of search form for the mobile view and the desktop view.